# -[NSString stringByAppendingPathComponent:] or just -[NSString stringByAppendingFormat:] for NSStrings for NSURLs?

Tags: objective-c, foundation

When calling `+[NSURL URLWithString:]` I have two options for building my URLs:

```
[[@"http://example.com" stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"foo"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bar"]
```

or

```
[@"http://example.com" stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@/%@",@"foo",@"bar"];
```

`-[NSString stringByAppendingPathComponent:]` seems like the more correct answer, but do I lose anything using `-[NSString stringByAppendingFormat:]` besides handling double-slashes as in the following case?

```
// http://example.com/foo/bar
[[@"http://example.com/" stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/foo"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bar"] 

// http://example.com//foo/bar  oops!
[@"http://example.com/" stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@/%@",@"foo",@"bar"];
```

Comment: `stringByAppendingPathComponent` will, in theory, use the "system path separator" vs the path separator hard-wired into your format, making your code (slightly more) system-independent.  But of course, Objective-C isn't very commonly used on Windoze, so this isn't a big issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're working with URLS, you should use the `NSURL` methods:

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://example.com"];
url = [[url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"foo"] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"bar"]
```

---

*or in Swift*

```
var url = NSURL.URLWithString("http://example.com")
url = url.URLByAppendingPathComponent("foo").URLByAppendingPathComponent(".bar")
```

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into a problem with stringByAppendingPathComponent: it removes double slashes everywhere!:

```
NSString* string1 = [[self baseURL] stringByAppendingString:partial];
NSString* string2 =  [[self baseURL] stringByAppendingPathComponent:partial];

NSLog(@"string1 is %s", [string1 UTF8String]);
NSLog(@"string2 is %s", [string2 UTF8String]);
```

for a baseURl of https://blah.com

and a partial of /moreblah

Produces the two strings:

2012-09-07 14:02:09.724 myapp string1 is https://blah.com/moreblah

2012-09-07 14:02:09.749 myapp string2 is https:/blah.com/moreblah

But for some reason my calls to blah.com to get resource work with the single slash. But it indicates to me that stringByAppendingPathComponent is for paths - NOT urls.

This is on iPhone 4 hardware running iOS 5.1.

I outputted the UTF8 strings as I wanted to make sure that the debugger output I was seeing was believable.

So I guess I am saying - don't use path stuff on URLs, use some home brew or a library.

Comment: The double slashes being reduced to a single slash is likely the result of a call to [`stringByStandardizingPath`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByStandardizingPath) by the path methods so it is not for URLs. BTW I updated my answer right after I replied to you.

Comment: It may be that it is new behavoir (in the past year or so) - I think that paths with '//' and '..' can be used for nefarious activity (eg to try to go somewhere 'different' in the file system.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

<s>[NSString pathWithComponents:@[@"http://example.com", @"foo", @"bar"]]</s>

As pointed out in the comments a `/` gets stripped from protocol when using the methods from `NSPathUtitlites.h`, so that is the obvious downfall. The solution I could come up with that is closest to the original one I posted is:

```
[@[ @"http://example.com", @"foo", @"bar" ] componentsJoinedByString:@"/"]
```

You will just need to use a literal for the path separator which is what [`NSString` does](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/ManipulatingPaths.html).

> `NSString` represents paths generically with ‘/’ as the path separator
>   and ‘.’ as the extension separator.

Comment: I get this stripping the // from the URL:   output is http:/example.com/foo/bar , which is bad.  See below.

Answer (score 0):

the point of stringByAppendingPathComponent is to handle double slashes, however, you could do something like:

```
[[@"http://example.com/" stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", @"foo", @"bar"]]
```